# Angular js - isDate() won't work

Tags: javascript, string, angularjs, date

Im trying checking if a value is a date like this:

```
var input = "2014-04-01T15:22:30.000Z";

var dateTime = {
    year: $filter('date')(input,'yyyy'),
    day: $filter('date')(input,'EEE'),
    dayNum: $filter('date')(input,'d'),
    month: $filter('date')(input,'MMM'),
    hours:$filter('date')(input,'H'),
    mins: $filter('date')(input,'m'),
    seconds:$filter('date')(input,'ss')
};

if(angular.isDate(dateTime.year+' '+dateTime.month+' '+dateTime.dayNum)) { 
    // always false 
}
```

why is always false?

The year,month etc pieces are correctly filtered :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following statement is always false, maybe your assumption about how isDate works is incorrect?

```
angular.isDate('2014 Mar 1');
```

Here's the [source code for the isDate function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L499). You'll see that it checks whether the supplied value is a javascript Date object.

```
function isDate(value){
  return toString.call(value) === '[object Date]';
}
```

You might wonder why angular allows you to do the following:

```
var input = "2014-04-01T15:22:30.000Z";
var year = $filter('date')(input,'yyyy');
```

It's because the [date filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) actually converts your input into a date before returning a formatted copy.  So, with the date filter, it lets you pass in a string, but the isDate function requires a Date object.

Answer (score 0):

`dateTime.year+' '+dateTime.month+' '+dateTime.dayNum` is a string, not a date object.